# Want to save Text of Dropdown to database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public List<SelectListItem> getTickerName()
{
    List<SelectListItem> lstTicker = new List<SelectListItem>();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //ds = BasicBoObj.getDatasetSP("sp_TickerNameForCompanies");
    ds = BasicBoObj.getDatasetSP("sp_ConfAdminCompanies");

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        lstTicker.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Convert.ToString(dr["DisplayCompanyName"]), Value = Convert.ToString(dr["code"]) });
    }
    return lstTicker;
}
```

I want to access the `Text` of this `lstTicker`.

In `Text`, I am passing the name of Company and in "Value" I am passing ID to the stored procedure.

How could I only access the "Text" In which I have the name of the company, I want to store that in database

I am accessing the value

```
presentationParentObj.lstCompany = getTickerName();

public List<SelectListItem> lstCompany { get; set; }


@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PresentationParentObj.Year, Model.lstYear, "Select Year", new { style = "vertical-align: top;", @id = "lstYear", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: how do you read " lstTicker " selected text ?

Comment: It looks like is missing some code to understand the steps you are taking, but for the info you´ve provided, I would say that you have two options. 1. In the `SelectLisItem` put the Company Name as the value (I do not recommend). 2. When you receive the request get into the server with the code (value set in SelectLisItem) you fetch the Company Name and after that do your Save. Regards.

Comment: where are you getting `id` and `CompanyName` from? Where is the `Company` you want to save, where is that also passed?

Comment: From the store proc  sp_ConfAdminCompanies   Iam getting the Id and name , In that Text i am passing the name and  In "value" I am passing the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

Controller/Model:

```
public class MyViewModelSO
{
    public int selectedValue { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> tickers = HomeController.getTickerName();
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index2007(MyViewModelSO myViewModel) 
    {
        //save
        var value = myViewModel.tickers.Where(r => r.Value == myViewModel.selectedValue.ToString()).
            Select(s => s.Text).ToList();

        //put breakpoint here to see value contains text
        //...rest of save

        return View(myViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Index2007()
    {
        var myViewModel = new MyViewModelSO();
        return View(myViewModel);
    }

    public static List<SelectListItem> getTickerName()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstTicker = new List<SelectListItem>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\sqlexpress;DataBase={MyDB};Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ConfAdminCompanies", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // execute the command
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // iterate through results, printing each to console
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    lstTicker.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = rdr["DisplayCompanyName"].ToString(),
                        Value = rdr["code"].ToString()
                    });

                }
            }
        }
        return lstTicker;
    }
```

View:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.MyViewModelSO
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index2007</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(r => r.selectedValue)</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedValue,
                            new SelectList(Model.tickers, "Value", "Text"))

                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="SaveTextNotValue" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have Edited My quest can you please look into it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the property of **selectedItem.Text** here is the example:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FruitModel fruit)
    {
        fruit.Fruits = PopulateFruits();
        var selectedItem = fruit.Fruits.Find(p => p.Value == fruit.FruitId.ToString());
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            selectedItem.Selected = true;
            ViewBag.Message = "Fruit: " + selectedItem.Text;
            ViewBag.Message += "\\nQuantity: " + fruit.Quantity;
        }

        return View(fruit);
    }
```

Source : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Get-DropDownList-Selected-Text-and-Selected-Value-in-Controller.aspx

Hope it will be helpful

Thanks

Karthik